# How to include CodeSynthesis-XSD into own application?

Tags: c++, qt, xsd, xsd.exe, codesynthesis

1.) How can i include the CodeSynthesis-XSD Code-generation into my application, so when i give the application (QT in Visual Studio 10) to someone other he doesnt need to install Code-Synthesis?

---

2.) And how can i specify the output-directory of the `.cpp` and `.h` files? `xsd help` doesnt list such an option? i generate like this with the tree:

```
>xsd cxx-tree "C:\scheme.xsd"
```

**-> solved via a "cd" (Change-Directory) before executing xsd**

---

3.) i get warnings that i dont know how to solve:

```
warning F002: attribute 'value' is implicitly of anySimpleType
info: did you forget to specify 'type' attribute?
warning T004: generating parsing functions for 18 global elements
info: use --root-element-* options to specify document root(s)
```

are there additional parameters that arent listed in `xsd help`?

Comment: multiple questions in the same question. It's better to seperate them into multiple stackoverflow questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The runtime library (libxsd) is header-only so there is no need for the end user to install it if you    are providing your software in compiled form.
2. Use the `--output-dir` option

```
    erik@ubuntu:~$ xsdcxx help cxx-tree 2>&1 | grep -A1 output-dir
      --output-dir <dir>          Write generated files to <dir> instead of current
                                  directory.
```

3. Regarding "warning T004":

```
    erik@ubuntu:~$ xsdcxx help cxx-tree 2>&1 | grep -A1 root-element
      --root-element-first        Treat only the first global element as a document
                                  root.
      --root-element-last         Treat only the last global element as a document
                                  root.
      --root-element-all          Treat all global elements as document roots.
      --root-element-none         Don't treat any global elements as document roots.
      --root-element <element>    Treat only <element> as a document root. Repeat
                                  this option to specify more than one root element.
```

If you don't specify any of these options, `--root-element-all` is implied but you will   see the "warning T004". 
  If `--root-element-all` is what you want, I suggest adding that option to make the warning go away.

Regarding "warning F002": Sorry, I don't know.

Note: "2>&1" will not be needed in the future when CodeSynthesis XSD will start printing the help text to stdout.
     http://codesynthesis.com/pipermail/xsd-users/2012-March/003577.html

Comment: I want xsd to create the output directory if it does't exist, is there a way to force that too? `--output-dir`seems to direct to it but it doesn't create the folder if it doesn't exit.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the "warning F002", got the similar problem and figured out that it's being raised when declaring attributes without specifying a concrete type.